# Can I access internet by connecting ethernet to a wifi repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, repeater

For some reason, my wireless won't work, but ethernet works fine. I would like to use a (repeater) wireless router to repeat another one and then connect to that repeater router through ethernet. Is it possible?

Comment: Depends entirely on the repeater and how much networking hardware is on the repeater. The ethernet port on the repeaters Ive seen is just an access port for configuration. Most manufacturers will probably not include a switch in their basic repeaters in order to differentiate it as a product from their more expensive routers. However you can use many bona fide routers as a wifi-ethernet bridge easily.

Comment: I intended to use a full featured wireless router TPLINK to act as a bridge. So it's possible, right?

Comment: Most likely yes, the hardware should support it just fine. Practically every wifi controller that can be set to AP can easily be used in infrastructure mode, and setting the device up to forwarding is straightforward even in embedded OS's.  The question is how much configuration control the manufacturer gives you to make it happen. I wouldn't know that without having one in front of me.

Comment: Keep in mind if this router is currently configured as a repeater (range extender) it may not function as such if you configure it as a wifi-ethernet bridge.